Publishing anonymously; using a "proxy" author
I'd like to submit a short story for publication with (publisher here).
However, I'm a very private person and I'm not entirely happy with the protections afforded by a pseudonym.
If I were to sell my story to a trusted associate for a peppercorn, could they submit for publication as if they'd written it, then pass along any payment to me? Kind of like a ghost writer.
Or are there legal issues here I'm not aware of?
Edit: Asker is in the United Kingdom.

You can do that. Legal issues only arise if the text is illegal (e.g. child pornography or slander or copyright infringment) or if the person who now owns your copyright becomes rich from your writing (e.g. when it gets turned into a movie) and doesn't share their revenue with you or if your author persona becomes famous and your "trusted associate" sells your identity to the highest bidder.
Instead of selling your story, you can also hire an attorney to act as a go-between. Only the attorney will know your true identity and the publisher will only be in contact with the attorney. You retain the rights to your story and all the revenues (minus the attorney's fees) are yours. Also, an attorney will not reveal your identity unless there is a legal problem and a court of law forces them to.
But all of this is unnecessary. Any literary agent or publisher will keep your confidence if you want to publish under a pseudonym. And you don't have to pay them (as you would the attorney) nor would you have to sell your rights to someone (as with your "trusted associate"). Any literary agent or publisher who wants to stay in business will keep your identity in confidence. They do this quite regularly.
Also consider that as a writer you will want to build a brand. Readers look for new books by authors they love. If you publish through some middleman, all your future publications have to go through them as well. Otherwise you cannot easily use the same author name for your future publications – or how do you want to explain to your publisher that you are in fact the same person when your previous publications were submitted by someone else?
In summary, I wouldn't do what you plan. Instead submit to an agent, and if one of them wants to take you on, discuss publishing under a pseudonym with them.

Just a follow up Q, what is the legal significant of pseudonym? Since it is not a copyright stuff, can anyone steal/modify/distort your pseudonym? Can a person have multiple pseudonyms?

@NaveedAhmed I'm sorry, but was my answer helpful to you? If it was, please consider upvoting it. To me that is a sign that you respect the effort I put into it. In my culture it is considered polite to thank the person helping you before you ask them for even more help.

Yes, thank you, your answer is very helpful that's why I considered upvoting. However, according to how the system is designed, upvoting/downvoting is generally anonymous.

@NaveedAhmed Thank you. Yes, a person can have multiple pseudonyms. In fact, many writers have a different pseudonym for each genre they write in, to keep the brands distinct from each other. And here is a Q&A about using an existing name (or pseudonym) as one's pseudonym: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49712/can-i-use-a-real-persons-name-as-a-pseudonym

Ben's answer may very well be correct where he lives, but as is often the case with legal matters, it heavily depends on jurisdiction, and you don't mention yours.
In my country, this would NOT be legal, because attribution rights of an author are impossible to give up. You cannot legally make an agreement with a friend that they sign your work with their name as the author, even if both of you consent to it.
It is perfectly legal (if weird) to choose a pseudonym that "just happens to" read the same as your friend's name, but for your friend to act as the author (and for instance sign a publishing contract) would be illegal and any such action could be disputed and declared invalid.
I'd like to note that the privacy of a pseudonym or anonymously published work is protected by law. (It's part of the attribution rights to have the work attributed to you under the name of your choice.) To make an author's identity known without their consent is very much a violation. And an author doesn't have to disclose their identity to anyone. You can sign a publishing contract using your pseudonym and it's perfectly valid and binding.
You could of course give the power of attorney to your friend, or even to yourself, under your pseudonym.
So, to sum this all up - check your jurisdiction!

Can I ask your jurisdiction? I'm in the UK :)

@ConnieMnemonic I don't feel entirely comfortable disclosing, but I certainly can tell you that it isn't any part of the UK, so not directly relevant to you. I've taken the liberty to add this in the question; feel free to rephrase, but please keep the information included. (Also, is the UK really a single jurisdiction? If it isn't then you might have to narrow it down even more: England? Scotland? Cayman Islands?)
